# Is there any other known relationship between even perfect numbers and odd perfect numbers, apart from their multiplicative forms?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, open-problem

(Note: This was cross-posted from MO, because it was not well-received there.  Will delete the [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427203) in a few.)

Observe that an even perfect number $M = (2^p - 1)\cdot{2^{p - 1}}$ and an odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ have similar multiplicative forms.  (Indeed, it is conjectured that $k=1$, and this prediction goes back to Descartes ($1638$).)

Here is my initial question:

**INITIAL QUESTION**

> Is there any other known relationship between even perfect numbers and odd perfect numbers, apart from their multiplicative forms?

I ask because of a related query [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406701).

Indeed, if we could show that $$\left|2^r - t\right| = 1,$$
for $r$ and $t$ satisfying $n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$ and $\gcd(2, t)=1$, then we would have a proof for $n < q^k$, which together with [Brown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591)'s estimate $q < n$ ($2016$) would yield a **refutation** of Descartes's Conjecture that $k = 1$.

---

Note that, for even perfect numbers, we actually have
$$(2^p - 1) - 2^{p-1} = 2^{p-1} - 1 = \bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 1\bigg)\bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - 1\bigg) = ab,$$
where the factorization works whenever $M \neq 6$.  (Note that $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.)

We compute that
$$\left|a - b\right| = 2.$$

---

**DISCUSSION**

In the hyperlinked [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406701), the following (summarized) cases were considered for odd perfect numbers, which we now examine for even perfect numbers:

**Case 1:**
$$2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} < \min(a,b) = 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - 1$$

> Notice that **Case 1** clearly does not hold.

**Case 2:**
$$\min(a,b) = 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - 1 < 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} < \max(a,b) = 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 1$$

> Notice that **Case 2** clearly holds.

It follows (from mimicking the resulting inequality $q^k < n\cdot{\left|2^r - t\right|}$ for odd perfect numbers) that
$$2^p - 1 < {2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}}\cdot{\left|a - b\right|} = {2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}}\cdot{2} = {2^{\dfrac{p+1}{2}}}.$$

This last inequality implies that
$$p < -\dfrac{2\bigg(\log(2) - \log(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6})\bigg)}{\log(2)} \approx 1.89997,$$
which is a contradiction to $p \geq 2$.

**Case 3:**
$$\max(a,b) = 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 1 < 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}$$

> Notice that **Case 3** clearly does not hold.

---

Note that for even perfect numbers, we **do have**
$$2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} < 2^p - 1$$
which "*mimics*" the conjecture $n < q^k$ for odd perfect numbers above.

---

Here is my final question for this post:

**FINAL QUESTION**

> Does the exhaustion of all possible cases in the **DISCUSSION** section essentially disprove the existence of odd perfect numbers?

---

**Edit (Added on July 25, 2022 - 7:15 PM Manila time)**

On second thought, I think the argument above **only rules out** $\left|a - b\right| = 2$.  Since $ab = 2^{p-1} - 1$ is always odd, and moreover, that $ab \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ always holds (for $p > 2$), then we can write
$$\left|a - b\right| = 2^y z$$
for some $y \geq 1$ and $z$ satisfying $\gcd(2,z)=1$.  (Notice that $\left|a - b\right| = 2^y z$ is **not a square**.)

*THIS WILL THEN ENTAIL A CAREFUL CONSIDERATION OF VARIOUS CONSEQUENT CASES.*

---

**Edit (Added on July 26, 2022 - 10:25 PM Manila time)**

Since $ab \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ holds, then either
$$\begin{cases}
{a \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
 b \equiv 3 \pmod 4
}
\end{cases}
$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
{a \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\
 b \equiv 1 \pmod 4
}
\end{cases}
$$
Either way, we obtain
$$2^y z = \left|a - b\right| \equiv 2 \pmod 4$$
so that we know that $y = 1$.

By the considerations in the **DISCUSSION** above, we finally obtain that
$$z \geq 3 > 2 = 2^y.$$

Therefore, we know that
$$\min(2^y, z) = 2^y = 2$$
while
$$\max(2^y, z) = z.$$

Comment: I do know that if $O = u^v w^2$ is a perfect number (either odd or even), then we have the equations
$$\gcd(w^2, \sigma(w^2)) = \frac{\sigma(w^2)}{u^v} = \frac{2w^2}{\sigma(u^v)} = \frac{D(w^2)}{s(u^v)} = \frac{2s(w^2)}{D(u^v)},$$
where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$, $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$, and $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the [aliquot sum](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

(**This is a partial answer.**)

---

Let $(2^p - 1)\cdot{2^{p-1}}$ be an even perfect number **distinct from** $6$.

Recall that $\left|a - b\right| = 2z$ for some **integer** $z$ satisfying $\gcd(2,z)=1$, and that $z \geq 3$.  Note that it is given that
$$ab = 2^{p-1} - 1 = \bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 1\bigg)\bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - 1\bigg).$$

Notice that
$$\gcd\Bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 1, 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - 1\Bigg) = 1.$$

We consider the following subcases.

**Case 1:** $2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} > z > 2$

We obtain from **Case 1** that
$$\bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - z\bigg)\bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 2\bigg) > 0$$
which can be re-expressed as
$$2^{p-1} - 2z > {2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}}\cdot\left|2 - z\right|$$
from which it follows that
$$ab + 1 - \left|a - b\right| > \sqrt{ab + 1}\cdot\left|2 - \dfrac{\left|a - b\right|}{2}\right|. \tag{1}$$

Note: I tried asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+ab+%2B+1+-+Abs%28a+-+b%29+%3E+sqrt%28ab+%2B+1%29%28Abs%282+-+%28Abs%28a+-+b%29%2F2%29%29%29+over+the+natural+numbers) and it **does seem** to yield solutions to Inequality **(1)** where all the variables are positive-valued.  I am therefore led to conjecture that this the correct case to consider (see **Case 2** below).  Indeed, we know that $2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} < 2^p - 1$ trivially holds.

**Case 2:** $2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} \geq 2 > z$

We obtain from **Case 2** that
$$2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} \geq 2 > z \geq 3$$
which is a contradiction.

**Case 3:** $z > 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} \geq 2$

We obtain from **Case 3** that
$$\bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 2\bigg)\bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - z\bigg) < 0$$
which can be re-expressed as
$$2^{p-1} - 2z < {2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}}\cdot{\left|2 - z\right|}$$
from which it follows that
$$ab + 1 - \left|a - b\right| < \sqrt{ab + 1}\cdot\left|2 - \dfrac{\left|a - b\right|}{2}\right|. \tag{2}$$

Note: I tried asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+ab+%2B+1+-+Abs%28a+-+b%29+%3C+sqrt%28ab+%2B+1%29%28Abs%282+-+%28Abs%28a+-+b%29%2F2%29%29%29+over+the+natural+numbers) and it **does seem** to yield solutions to Inequality **(2)** where all the variables are positive-valued.

**Case 4:** $2 \geq 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} > z$

We obtain from **Case 4** that
$$2 \geq 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} > z \geq 3,$$
which is a contradiction.

**Case 5:** $z > 2 \geq 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}$

We obtain from **Case 5** that
$$2z = \left|a - b\right| > 2^{p-1} = ab + 1$$
which yields the contradiction
$$\bigg(a \geq 1\bigg) \land \bigg(b < \dfrac{a-1}{a+1}\bigg).$$

**Case 6:** $2 > z > 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}$

We obtain from **Case 6** that
$$2 > z > 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}$$
which implies that
$$1> \dfrac{p-1}{2}.$$
We obtain finally that
$$p < 3$$
which contradicts our requirement that $p > 2$.

Comment: Note that the cases in this answer can be summarized as follows: **Case 1** or **Case 2**: $$\max(2^y, z) \leq 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}},$$ **Case 3** or **Case 4**: $$\min(2^y, z) \leq 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} \leq \max(2^y, z),$$ and **Case 5** or **Case 6**: $$2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} \leq \min(2^y, z).$$

Comment: Note that the summary of cases in this answer can now be updated as follows: 

**Case 1** or **Case 2**: $$\max(2,z) = z \leq 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}},$$

**Case 3** or **Case 4**: $$\min(2,z) = 2 \leq 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} < \max(2,z) = z$$

and **Case 5** or **Case 6**:  $$2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} \leq \min(2,z) = 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

(**This post is currently under construction - I will come back to it as soon as time permits.**)

Posted this other answer, as the earlier one is getting too long already.

---

**SUMMARY OF RESULTS**

The remaining cases to consider are:

> **Case 1:** $2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} > z > 2$

and

> **Case 3:** $z > 2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} \geq 2.$

---

In general, consider the relations
$$\Bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} + 1\Bigg)\Bigg(2^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}} - 1\Bigg) = 2^{p-1} - 1 = \left|2^p - 1 - 2^{p-1}\right| = ab \tag{1}$$
and
$$\left|a - b\right| = 2z \tag{2}.$$

From relation **(1)**, note that only finitely many possibilities may be determined for $a$ and $b$, if you fix $p$.

Thereafter, from relation **(2)**, one can solve for $z$ using the values for $a$ and $b$ obtained from the previous step.

---

In this way, the checking of the various remaining subcases under **Case 1** and **Case 3** is reduced to a finite computation.